# How to get the geometry data out of one table into another?

Tags: postgresql, join, postgis, qgis

I have a question about a join i wanna do between two tables. I have one table which hasn't got the geometry data in it that i need from another table. Is there a simple method to get that data in my other table?

Thnx[image: See screenshot over here]

Comment: You should include you db schema and sample data. We cant copy/paste from picture so text code will be more friendly. Also please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
   And [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [UPDATE syntax](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-update.html) is:

```
[ WITH [ RECURSIVE ] with_query [, ...] ]
UPDATE [ ONLY ] table [ [ AS ] alias ]
    SET { column = { expression | DEFAULT } |
          ( column [, ...] ) = ( { expression | DEFAULT } [, ...] ) } [, ...]
    [ FROM from_list ]
    [ WHERE condition | WHERE CURRENT OF cursor_name ]
    [ RETURNING * | output_expression [ [ AS ] output_name ] [, ...] ]
```

```
UPDATE TableB AS B
SET geom = A.geom
FROM TableA AS A
WHERE B.join_id = A.id
```

**NOTE**

I dont see column `geom` on `TableB` so you may need create the column first

```
ALTER TABLE TableB ADD COLUMN geom geometry;
```